# Concat JSON object into array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, concatenation

How can I concat JSON objects if the first object is:

```
{
     "total": "2"
}
```

And second:

```
[
     "player1": {
          "score": "100",
          "ping": "50"
     },
     "player2": {
          "score": "100",
          "ping": "50"
     }
]
```

If I want final result to look like:

```
{
     "total": "2",
     {
          "player1": {
               "score": "100",
               "ping": "50"
          },
          "player2": {
               "score": "100",
               "ping": "50"
          }
     }
}
```

I am trying to do it in JavaScript.

**Update**

The final result is not a valid array.
What about this?

```
{
     [
          "player1": {
               "score": "100",
               "ping": "50"
          },
          "player2": {
               "score": "100",
               "ping": "50"
          }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Your final result is invalid JSON/JavaScript.

Comment: This is NOT a  valid JSON format, and you ARRAY is an invalid Array

Comment: the **what about this** section in your question is not a valid object cause it's missing a property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in the comments,
 you're trying to append an **invalid Array** getting as a result an **invalid JSON** tree.

To validate an expected JSON you can test it here: http://jsonlint.com/

**What's wrong 1**:

```
[ "player1" : { "score": "100", "ping": "50"} ] // Array ??
            ^ invalid delimiter (should be ,)
```

**What's wrong 2** in the expected result:

```
 {
     "property" : "value" ,
     "total" : "2" ,
          { "player1" : { "score": "100", "ping": "50" }
     ^^^^^ where's the property here???  
 }
```

**What you can do:**

```
var myObject = {"total":"2"};    
var players = {
         "player1": {
              "score": "100",
              "ping": "50"
         },
         "player2": {
              "score": "100",
              "ping": "50"
         }
};

myObject.players = players;

console.log( myObject );
```

which will result in:

```
[object Object] {
  players: [object Object] {
    player1: [object Object] { ... },
    player2: [object Object] { ... }
  },
  total: "2"
}
```

---

**Object Literal** needs a comma separated `PROPERTY : VALUE` pair model

```
{
   "property1" : val,
   "property2" : [],
   "property3" : "String",
   "property4" : {}
}
```

The above is a **valid JSON** cause implies that your property names are wrapped in double quotes `" "`.

```
"property" : value
```

**Array** (as seen in your Question) cannot be separated by `:` but with `,`

```
myArr = ["string", {}, value]; // is a valid Array.
```

with object:

```
myArr = ["string", {"objectProperty":"val"}, value];
```

Now to get a *key value* out of Array:

```
myArr[0] // "string"
myArr[1] // {object Object}
myArr[1].objectProperty // "val" // get Object property value
```

So as seen from above Arrays are values stored in *numbered keys* (0 zero based), while Objects are *property - value* pairs. What they have in common is the `comma (,)` delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the link and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid. If you want something valid, you need to do something like

```
{
  "total": "2",
  "players": [
     "player1": {
          "score": "100",
          "ping": "50"
     },
     "player2": {
          "score": "100",
          "ping": "50"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't a correct JSON object, you should do it like this

```
var x = { "total": "2" }
x.players = playerArray
```